# Magento 1.9 Set an Attribute value calling another value (weight)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

So, right now i have 2 shipping options, and since shipping is by weight and my site is B2B, customers want to know the exact final price they are paying, without reaching to cart, for every single product.

So, on the additional information block, i have the weight to display, and i want to add another 2 attributes, one for each shipping cost, the thing is that on each of this attributes, i need to multiply the weight value to a cost per lb...

Example:
Regular shipping cost costs $5 per lb and Express $8 per lb

I have product A that weights 0.34 lbs

So what i need is that when i go into the product page, in the additional info, to see this 2 attributes:

- Regular Shipping: `(Value would be 0.34 * 5) $1.70`
- Express Shipping: `(Value 0.34 * 8) $2.72`

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

short answer: yes. 
it is for sure is possible.

Should't there be more calculation logic? Like minimal shipping cost/weight per carrier?

If you want to re-use magento logic, then a quote object has to be created. Which means putting this product into cart. But since you dont want this simply implement your own logic in a custom block and add it to additional info or whereever you need it.

Comment: I added the logic to the additional info tab, outside the foreach loop, but its not displaying, so im not sure if its the correct file... i modify the file

app/design/frontend/theme/default/template/catalog/product/view/attrbutes.phtml

Comment: depending on your theme and layout xml it can be located differently. Maybe you should expose how you implemented it or add some static content to check if it is the correct template.

Comment: @frenciaj Nope, you have tried to add the code to Vladimirs answer. Please try again. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58223650/edit) your question and add it there.